# React route with coreui - can't get any props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, core-ui

I am using coreui 4.1.0 (react). I can't get any props (like user_id). What am I doing wrong?

**UserListTable.js (Edit Button) // Updated**

```
<Link
  /to={`/user/edit-user/${item.user_id}`}
  className="btn btn-xl btn-outline-warning px-2"
>
  Edit
</Link>
```

**coreui routes.js**

```
    const EditUser = React.lazy(() => import('./views/user/EditUser'))
```

and

```
    "path: '/user/edit-user/:user_id',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Edit User',
    component: EditUser
```

**EditUser.js**

```
const EditUser = (props) => {
          //const { user_id } = useParams
          const user_id = props.match.params.user_id
    
          return (
            <CRow>
              <CCol xs={12}>
                <CCard className="mb-4">
                  <CCardHeader>
                    <strong>User-List</strong>
                  </CCardHeader>
                  <CCardBody>{`Hello ${user_id}`}</CCardBody>
                </CCard>
              </CCol>
            </CRow>
          )
        }
    
        export default EditUser
```

Thank you

UPDATE

I think this is the route.component.

"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
"react": "^17.0.2",

**AppContent.js (original coreui-file)**

```
// routes config
import routes from '../routes'

const AppContent = () => {
  return (
    <CContainer lg>
      <Suspense fallback={<CSpinner color="primary" />}>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, idx) => {
            return (
              route.component && (
                <Route
                  key={idx}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  name={route.name}
                  render={(props) => (
                    <>
                      <route.component {...props} />
                    </>
                  )}
                />
              )
            )
          })}
          <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </CContainer>
  )
}

export default React.memo(AppContent)
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: currentRoute is undefined
    getRouteName AppBreadcrumb.js:13
    getBreadcrumbs AppBreadcrumb.js:22
    getBreadcrumbs AppBreadcrumb.js:18
    AppBreadcrumb AppBreadcrumb.js:30
    React 13
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 6
```

Can you help me with this information?

**Added AppBreadcrumb.js (original from coreui)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

import routes from '../routes'

import { CBreadcrumb, CBreadcrumbItem } from '@coreui/react-pro'

const AppBreadcrumb = () => {
  const currentLocation = useLocation().pathname

  const getRouteName = (pathname, routes) => {
    const currentRoute = routes.find((route) => route.path === pathname)
    return currentRoute.name
  }

  const getBreadcrumbs = (location) => {
    const breadcrumbs = []
    location.split('/').reduce((prev, curr, index, array) => {
      const currentPathname = `${prev}/${curr}`
      breadcrumbs.push({
        pathname: currentPathname,
        name: getRouteName(currentPathname, routes),
        active: index + 1 === array.length ? true : false,
      })
      return currentPathname
    })
    return breadcrumbs
  }

  const breadcrumbs = getBreadcrumbs(currentLocation)

  return (
    <CBreadcrumb className="m-0 ms-2">
      <CBreadcrumbItem href="/">Home</CBreadcrumbItem>
      {breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => {
        return (
          <CBreadcrumbItem
            {...(breadcrumb.active ? { active: true } : { href: breadcrumb.pathname })}
            key={index}
          >
            {breadcrumb.name}
          </CBreadcrumbItem>
        )
      })}
    </CBreadcrumb>
  )
}

export default React.memo(AppBreadcrumb)
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant code? How are you declaring/rendering the routes and routed components? What version of `react-router` is used? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And also can you share what error are you getting or message.

Comment: Ok, so it seems you've a couple issues you are asking about. (1) for the route match param you just need to ensure the param you are accessing matches that defined in the route path. (2) We'd need to also see this `AppBreadcrumb` component to see what is going on there.

Comment: i am a real react newbie. can you explain this to me in more detail or what would i need to edit (file)?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get any props (like user_id). What am I doing wrong?

You've declared a route path `'/user/edit-user/:user_id'` for the routed component `EditUser`, and correctly pass the route props through to the component with `render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}`, and correctly access the `user_id` route path param with `const user_id = props.match.params.user_id;`... I see no issue here or any reason for `user_id` to not be defined.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: currentRoute is undefined
>     getRouteName AppBreadcrumb.js:13
>     getBreadcrumbs AppBreadcrumb.js:22
>     getBreadcrumbs AppBreadcrumb.js:18
>     AppBreadcrumb AppBreadcrumb.js:30
>     React 13
>     unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
>     React 6
> ```

`routes.find((route) => route.path === pathname)` can return undefined if no match is found, you need to check this condition prior to accessing `currentRoute.name`. Use either a null-check/guard-clause or the Optional Chaining operator to access into the potentially undefined object value.

```
const getRouteName = (pathname, routes) => {
  const currentRoute = routes.find((route) => route.path === pathname);
  return currentRoute && currentRoute.name;
};
```

or

```
const getRouteName = (pathname, routes) => {
  const currentRoute = routes.find((route) => route.path === pathname);
  return currentRoute?.name;
};
```

Comment: i'll do that. thank you for your help